# What is the ideal sheaf of a closed subset of a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, sheaf-theory, schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a scheme and let $Y \subseteq X$ be a closed subset. What is meant by the "ideal sheaf of the closed subset $Y$"? Normally to define the ideal sheaf of a closed *subscheme* we take the kernel of the morphism 
$$
i^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_{X} \longrightarrow i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}.
$$
But in Hartshorne III Theorem 3.7, we simply have a scheme $X$ with a closed subset $Y$, and he defines the ideal sheaf of $Y$. But $Y$ has no scheme structure, so if we want to define it as above, what is meant by $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$? Indeed we could put many different scheme structures on $Y$. Is there some more general definition of the ideal sheaf if we only specify a closed subset?

Comment: It's the reduced induced closed subscheme structure, see e.g. [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3).

Comment: There is a unique choice for a subscheme structure on $Y$ which is reduced, it is described in Hartshorne II Example 3.2.6. My guess is that that is the one that the author is thinking of.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had wondered if it was the reduced induced structure. So this is probably a very stupid question, but will the reduced induced structure correspond to the inverse image sheaf on the closed set? As in, $(Y, i^{*}\mathcal{O}_{X})$ where $i: Y \longrightarrow X$ is the inclusion? Possibly @MinseonShin will know if not Marc

Comment: Do you mean $(Y,i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X})$? If so the answer is no. For example, let $A$ be a local ring with residue field $k$, set $X := \operatorname{Spec} A$, and let $i : Y \to X$ be the inclusion of the closed point of $X$. Then $i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is the sheaf of rings on $Y$ corresponding to the ring $A$, whereas we'd want $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ to correspond to the ring $k$.